# Copy an XML file preserving closing tags of some elements

Tags: xml, haskell, whitespace, hxt

I'm hacking a thing that should copy an XML file and edit little part of
it. Editing now is OK, but interestingly enough copying may be quite
tricky. This is essentially «reverse engineering» work and now I know that I
should somehow preserve closing tags of some elements (even if the elements
contain only white space or are empty). The problem is when HXT reads
something like

```xml
<tag>
</tag>
```

it then prints it as

```xml
<tag/>
```

I can tell it to always use explicit closing tag (or whatever you call it)
specifying `withOutputXHTML` option for `writeDocument` function, however
there are elements that are written as

```xml
<tag/>
```

that should be copied «as is».

So, essentially my problem boils down to: «How to copy this file preserving
closing tags of some specific elements?»:

```xml
<foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
  <baz/>
</foo>
```

Simple copying program for reference/experiment:

```hs
module Main (main) where

import Control.Monad (void)
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

main :: IO ()
main = void $ runX $
       readDocument [ withValidate no ] "test.xml" >>>
       writeDocument [ withIndent yes
                     , withOutputEncoding isoLatin1
                     , withOutputXHTML ] "result.xml"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long, frustrating searching, I've decided to try every option in
[Text.XML.HXT.Arrow.XmlState](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState.html).
Some options just have no doc strings, so it's a guessing game.

Finally, I've found this marvel:

> [withNoEmptyElemFor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState.html#v:withNoEmptyElemFor) :: [String] -> SysConfig

Although it has no doc string, its name sounds quite promising. Indeed, with
help of this option we can specify names of elements which «cannot be
empty».

This option can be used with
[`writeDocument`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-WriteDocument.html#v:writeDocument)
or
[`configSysVars`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState.html#v:configSysVars).
I like the second arrow better because I can use it locally, it's useful if
you have several arrows that perform processing of slightly different
documents that may have different collections of tags that shouldn't be
empty (that's my case).

So, returning to my example, we can fix it by writing:

```hs
module Main (main) where

import Control.Monad (void)
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

main :: IO ()
main = void $ runX $
       readDocument [ withValidate no ] "test.xml" >>>
       writeDocument [ withIndent yes
                     , withOutputEncoding isoLatin1
                     , withNoEmptyElemFor ["bar"] ] "result.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful, whitespace preservation is the default behavior of xml-conduit. The following will not collapse your `<tag>` element, for example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Text.XML as X

main :: IO ()
main = do
    doc <- X.readFile X.def "foo.xml"
    X.writeFile X.def "bar.xml" doc
```